# how to select rows which satisfies multiple conditions in sql?

Tags: database, select

I have a table called transac(accnum,scriptname,transactiontype,quantity,price). I need to select the transaction which has specified accnum, scriptname and transactiontype.

Can I do this by using the query below?

```
Select accnum,scriptname,quantity,price 
From transac 
Where accnum = 10, scriptname = 'abcd' and transactiontype = 'sell';
```

Comment: Replace the comma in the WHERE clause with AND

Comment: @reaanb : can I use more than one AND ????

Comment: You have to use AND / OR to combine expressions in the WHERE clause.  It's like math with true/false instead of numerical expressions.

Comment: I have used AND command in WHERE clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used AND command in WHERE clause :

```
Select accnum,scriptname,quantity,price 
From transac 
Where accnum = 10 AND scriptname = 'abcd' AND transactiontype = 'sell';
```